# Windows GUI based tasks automation

Tags: windows, user-interface, automation, task

I am looking to automate below set of tasks on Windows-7, which is a mixture of mouse movements, selecting a option from a drop down list of a application in this case WinSCP, Enter some data using keyboard, and then press some menu button to do a task.

Example of the task

1. Open WinSCP for windows
2. From the drop down list, Select File Protocol as SCP(As seen in the image snapshots)
3. Enter IP address in the field Hostname, login name in the field User name and Password
4. Click Login

Even if some tool helps in automating Steps 1. to 4. above it should help.

Then next step is once the we open a WinSCP window showing folders on both the target and host, we need to do is get/copy some files from the target on to the host.

Could [Auto-It](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/) or some other tool help do it neatly.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could try [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/), or any other from [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GUI_testing_tools). You should also be able to do it with AutoHotKey or AutoIt if you figure out which key commands you need to press to do all the steps. (Like tab a few times, use arrow keys etc to move around the interface and fill in the settings)